# How do you create a blessed reference to a constant hash?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to create a proper blessed reference to a constant hash and the below code works but I'm not sure if its the proper 'Perl' way to do it.

```
package....

....
use Hash::Util qw<lock_hash>;

sub new {
    my ($self, $data, $left, $right) = @_;
    my %h = (DATA => $data, LEFT => $left, RIGHT => $right);
    my $r = bless \%h, $self;
    lock_hash($r->%*);
    $r;
}

1;
```

Any pointers or tips?

The Ullich update

```
package....

....
use Hash::Util qw<lock_hash>;

sub new {
    my ($self, $data, $left, $right) = @_;
    my %h = (DATA => $data, LEFT => $left, RIGHT => $right);
    lock_hashref(bless \%h, $self);#The Ullrich update
}

1;
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `lock_hashref($r)`?

Comment: @Ullrich Because I'm a Perl rookie who should have read a little further into the Hash::Util docs.

Comment: Some customs: the name `$self` is normally used for the object inside the class (package file), likely in analogy with other languages. The method `new` is normally called on a class (`ClassName->new`) so the first argument it receives is the class (package) name.  So it'd be like `sub new { my ($class, ...) = @_; my $self = { DATA => ... }; ... bless $self, $class; ... }`.  (But of course you can call these things anything you want.) See tutorial [perlootut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html), at least for these kinds of things.